# How can I sort ResultSet in java?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I can't do ORDER BY in the db by the way

Comment: 1. How big's the dataset? 2. Why is `ORDER BY` not an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the data out of the ResultSet into whatever object representation you want and then sort the data just as you would any other data at that point.

If you make use of Collections.Sort to perform your sorting on a complex object you will need to implement [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Answer (score 10):

Extract the results into a `List<YourResultType>` and use `Collections.sort()`. If you only ever need to sort in one "natural" order, then implement `Comparable<T>` in the result type itself... otherwise implement `Comparator<T>` once per sort order, and pass an instance of the relevant comparator to `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: ow do i put it back in rs? I've got a lot of things calling rs and i cant change that i need rs to stay as it is but sorted

Comment: @user521180: You don't. Redesign your solution. It's already bad enough that you can't use the database for one of the jobs it's designed for...

Comment: How to put it back in RS:  You can make use of a CachedRowSet, which implements ResultSet.  However, getting the entries in manually is a bit archaic.  It can be done,  nonetheless.

Answer (score 8):

You do `ORDER BY` in the DB.

You should reassess **why** you can't do this.  If someone asked "how do I insert a screw with a hammer?  I can't use a screwdriver by the way", it would be irresponsible not to persuade them that the screwdriver was the right solution in the first instance.

If you *really, really* can't order the result set natively, you're out of luck.  It's just a stream from the database, so you'd have to read it all into a temporary `List`, sort that collection and then go from there.  For small result sets this isn't likely to be a problem, but for large ones this will likely impose quite a hit on efficiency.

Comment: how do I put it back in rs after i sort it in the temp list?

Comment: You **can't** put it back in the `ResultSet`.  The ResultSet is by definition the rows that come back from your select statement, *in the order they are returned by the select statement*.  It sounds like you have an architectural problem as you shouldn't want to do this.  Once you have it in your `List`, why not continue using the elements directly?

Comment: One reason I could see not being able to sort in SQL ORDER BY is that no databases support natural sorting.

Comment: Another reason is that re-query the database every time can be an unnecessary waste of resources: if I already have my rs, I don't want to reload it at every sorting!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to sort it in the database before you run the query and then store in resultSet.

`SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY columnName ASC`

Is something like this that you want?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you would have to be responsible for implementing the ResultSet interface with a custom object that would give you the functionality you're looking for....sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in the query itself.   You order by a calculated column.  Your calculated column converts the natural value to a value that can be sorted numerically or alphabetically. You might define a "convert" function and call that function in the order by clause.

At some level the natural to numeric conversion must happen whether in your code or in the database. An algorithm is an algorithm no matter where it runs.

Comment: If your database does not support functions you can order by a "case statement". You can sneak in conversion logic within booleans checks. Fucntion is the better solution. But the solution you are looking for is without a doubt possible.

Comment: Here is a crazy exampe for SQLServer which sorts Even numbers on the top, odds on the bottom. (just as a natural sort example) select * 
from SomeTable 
order by case when (SomeNumber%2)=0 then 0
     else 1 end