# How do I sort String value taken from database (primary key) as integer in table?

Tags: java, database, user-interface, jtable, resultset

I have taken value from my database and put it into resultset and display it in JTable,but I am facing some sorting problem which is my primary key e.g. A1,A2,A3....A10,A11.But in my JTable,that primary key column has been displayed incorrectly.

> A11 A10 A1
>   A2
>   A3
>   A4

A11 should be at the last.Is there anyway to solve this issue??

Comment: This might help you.
 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379592/how-can-i-sort-resultset-in-java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379592/how-can-i-sort-resultset-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Strings` are ordered alphabetically by default. You need to implement your own `Comparator<String>`.

Try below comparator

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {

        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(str1.substring(1,str1.length()));
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(str2.substring(1, str2.length()));

        return num1 - num2;

    }
}
```

Run with your input

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] a = {"A11","A10", "A1" ,"A2", "A3", "A4"};

    Arrays.sort(a,new CustomComparator());
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(a).toString());
}
```

Output

```
[A1, A2, A3, A4, A10, A11]
```

Comment: Thank you,this has solved my problem.I implemented this code into custom comparator and put it into my sorter for my table.It works wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could write a custom `Comparator` for your table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try @Alex Suo to create a custom `Comparator`, or, update your `A1, A2` to `A01, A02` before insert into database.

The Arrays.sort() works pretty well for `A01, A02`:

```
String[] strArr = {"A05", "A10", "A02", "A23", "A11"};
    Arrays.sort(strArr);
    for(String s:strArr) {
        System.out.print(s + " ");
    }
```

Output: `A02, A05, A10, A11, A23,`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
    List values = Arrays.asList("A11","B1","A9", "Z9", "Z1", "A10", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4");
    System.out.println(values);
    Collections.sort(values,new SampleComparator());
    System.out.println(values);
```

Your comparator class is below

```
class SampleComparator implements Comparator<String>{

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2)
    {
        String[]  ob1 =o1.split("(?<=[\\w&&\\D])(?=\\d)");
        String[]  ob2 =o2.split("(?<=[\\w&&\\D])(?=\\d)");
        if(!ob1[0].equals(ob2[0])){
            return ob1[0].compareTo(ob2[0]);
        }
        Integer num1 = Integer.parseInt(ob1[1]);
        Integer num2 = Integer.parseInt(ob2[1]);
        return num1.compareTo(num2);
    }        
}
```

**Output**

```
[A11, B1, A9, Z9, Z1, A10, A1, A2, A3, A4]
[A1, A2, A3, A4, A9, A10, A11, B1, Z1, Z9]
```