# Java SQL Iterating 2 ResultSet and merging them

Tags: java, mysql, sql, resultset

let's say i have 2 queries and 2 `ResultSet`. the first one is members table query, while the second query is for other member datas. now i want to join the first resultset with the second one. for example it looks like this

```
ResultSet rsMember = psMembers.executeQuery();
ResultSet rsCustomValues = psCustomValues.executeQuery();

// object for mapping query results
MembersMapper memberMapper = new MembersMapper();

while (rsMember.next()) {
   memberMapper.setId(rsMember.getString("id"));
   memberMapper.setName(rsMember.getString("name"));
   memberMapper.setUsername(rsMember.getString("username"));
   memberMapper.setGroup(rsMember.getString("group_id"));

   List strCustomValues = new ArrayList<>();
   while(rsCustomValues.next()){
      // map the custom values
      Map<String, Object> mapTemp = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      mapTemp.put(FIELD_ID, rsCustomValues.getString("custom_field_id"));
      mapTemp.put(INTERNAL_NAME,
      rsCustomValues.getString("custom_field_internalname"));
      mapTemp.put(NAME,rsCustomValues.getString("custom_field_name"));

      strCustomValues.add(mapTemp);
   }  
   memberMapper.setCustomvalues(strCustomValues);
}
```

the problem is the second (inner while) query. what connects data between first and second resultset is member id, which is primary key in first table (first query) and foreign key in second query. so the second query will have member id in random order.

so how can i order the second query without having to put 'order by member_id' in the second query? i will have to avoid 'order by member_id' because it will take time to process.

**Edit:**  here's the scripts

First script

```
select 
mbr.*, usr.username, grp.name as groupname, grp.status 
from members mbr 
join users usr on mbr.id = usr.id 
join groups grp on mbr.group_id = grp.id 
where mbr.id > #id# 
order by id asc 
limit #limit#
```

Second script

```
    select 
    cfv.member_id as 'member_id', cf.id as 'custom_field_id', 
    cf.internal_name as 'custom_field_internalname', 
    cf.name as 'custom_field_name', cfv.string_value as 'cfv_stringvalue',
    cfv.possible_value_id as 'cf_possiblevalueid', cfvp.value as 'cfvpvalue' 
    from custom_field_values cfv 
    join custom_fields cf on cf.id = cfv.field_id 
    left join custom_field_possible_values cfvp on cfv.possible_value_id = cfvp.id 
    where exists(
    select * from (select id from members where id > #id# 
limit #limit# 
) result where result.id = cfv.member_id) 
    and cf.subclass = #subclass# 
    order by cfv.member_id asc
```

Comment: You can order the second query by sorting the result, either by asking the database using an `ORDER BY` clause, or by loading *all* the data into memory and sorting it there. Either way, the data will be sorted and that takes time. Only difference is whether that time is done by application server or database server, and the database server is likely much better at doing it, so: **Use `ORDER BY`.** Of course, the question remain: Why not do a SQL `JOIN`? It's what they are for.

Comment: `let's say i have 2 queries` ... please show us the queries.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i've updated the script.. kindly check it

Comment: These are large disparate queries and therefore running them separately might make sense.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to fetch the second result set to an object representation and sort it out.

See a similar question here [How can I sort ResultSet in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4379592/227775)

Comment: Which one is faster? Sorting in db using order by or sorting it in my java code?

Comment: I think its better to sort using order by as the db will take care of that. And mostly it will yield better performance.